# Sitewide Volume control in Html

Tags: javascript, html, audio, cookies, web

for a website with a focus on audio I need the ability of Background sounds and onclick sounds. I think I am able to integrate that, but I also need a stop/play button and a volume control that works sidewide (that means the site should remember the volume value and if to play or not after page reload or page change).

Does anybody know a method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the tags.

Cookies.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html — this may help.
Just save the cookie named "volume" (for example) every time the volume changes and read it on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either a Javascript variable that saves the state of the volume or a server side variable.
Remember that there is no way to play the music in background while loading a new page unless you use ajax to load contents.